# Vdisk (vhd) to physical

Tags: windows-7, citrix, vhd

I have a VHD file that was created by a citrix provisioning server. It is specific to a computer model.
I was wanting to transfer the vhd onto the physical disk.
Can anyone think of a way to do this? 
I then want to be able to boot off the physical hard disk like it was before I converted it to vdisk (vhd)
It is a windows 7 vhd.
Thanks

Comment: Exact Duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/40294/copying-a-vhd-to-a-physical-disk

Comment: On this page you will find two programs, each for x86-32 and x86-64 bit. It is a free tool to dump the VHD contents/structure to a physical drive (e.g. a HDD). http://forum.sysinternals.com/vhd2disk_topic27311.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

since its win7 just boot the vhd natively!

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799299(WS.10).aspx

Comment: That means I have to have an OS on there already (windows 7).
Not quite what I had in mind. I ended up using a program called macrium reflect to clone the vdisk to a physical hard drive in a sata caddy.

Comment: @johnyV no boot from vhd does not require an OS already there, it just boots the vhd as a filesystem.

Answer (score -2):

There are various P-to-V and V-to-P utilities on the market. There is more than likely one that can convert a VHD back onto a physical drive.

Outside of that route, you can also setup a VM to mount the VHD along side the RAW physical disk. You can then transfer the VHD to the physical drive with any various partition utility, backup application, etc.

Comment: No use in your post, no single utility proposed, just babbling